# Empty variable after transfer from twigg to javascript (symfony)

Tags: javascript, arrays, symfony, object, is-empty

When I pass the variable from twig to javascript, and display it in the console it returns an empty object.

**The controller that sends variable $user to twig**

```
$user = $userRepository->findAll();
    $hall = $hallRepository->findAll();

    return $this->render('pages/leader_hall/home.html.twig', [
        'leadersHall' => $leadersHall,
        'user'=> $user,
        'hall' => $hall
    ]);
```

**Here is the twig dump which sends me the data correctly(The data is correctly sent and completed**

```
"user" => array:7 [▼
0 => App\Entity\User {#783 ▶}
1 => App\Entity\User {#615 ▶}
2 => App\Entity\User {#655 ▶}
3 => App\Entity\User {#392 ▶}
4 => App\Entity\User {#796 ▶}
5 => App\Entity\User {#602 ▶}
6 => App\Entity\User {#608 ▶}
```

]

**The javascript code to retrieve the variable User**

```
var user = JSON.parse('{{ user | json_encode| raw}}')
        console.log(user)
```

the returned log (an array containing an empty object)

```
[
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{}
```

]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Isn't it that twig when printing instances of entities uses sort of serialization behind the scenes? The data is there, you just get nothing. I'd try serializing stuff in the controller manually and only then passing it to the template.

Comment: Can you show your twig file where you use the $user array please ?

Comment: @entio Thank you very much, it was enough just to serialize $user in the controller as you said

Comment: Check. Mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved, it was necessary to serialize $user in the controller

```
$user = $userRepository->findAll();
    $hall = $hallRepository->findAll();

    $encoder = new JsonEncoder();
    $defaultContext = [
        AbstractNormalizer::CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_HANDLER => function ($object, $format, $context) {
            return $object->getName();
        },
    ];
    $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, null, null, null, $defaultContext);

    $serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer], [$encoder]);
    $userSerialze = $serializer->serialize($user, 'json');


    return $this->render('pages/leader_hall/home.html.twig', [
        'leadersHall' => $leadersHall,
        'hall' => $hall,
        'user' => $userSerialze
    ]);
```